# How can I use a for loop to load elements into each of my arrays and then output the sum of each array into a sum array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;   

int main() 
{      
    /*      
    For this version, the matrices are square (defined by size, which is a maximum of 10).
    Thus, m & n (rows & columns) are the same.
    Later versions can allow the number of rows and columns to be different. 

    size - the dimension of both matrices.  
    m - the number of rows   
    n - the number of columns  
    c - the delimiter of the outer loop         
    d - the delimiter of the inner loop 

    first  - the first matrix  
    second - the second matrix 
    sum - holds the sum of the 2 matrices      
    */ 

    int size, m, n, c, d, first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10]; 

    cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns of matrices: ";         
    cin >> size;  m = size; n = size;    

    // Load the first matrix 
    cout << "Enter the elements of first matrix: "; 

    // Load the second matrix    

    cout << "Enter the elements of second matrix: ";    

    // Sum the elements of the matrices 

    // Print the sum matrix

    cout << "Hit any key to continue" << endl; 

    system ("pause");    return 0; 
}
```

Hello Everyone,

I am working on a C++ application that will load elements into the first array which is 10 row by 10 column and will load elements into a second array that is also a 10 by 10 and then add each array elements together and put them in an array called sum. For example, in real when you do addition of matrices, you would do something like this below, but my array are more complex then this. The question is how use a nested for loop to load elements into each of my arrays. Any examples would be much appreciated!!! Here is the code I have so far. I know how to output elements in an array, but I never loaded elements into an array using for loop.

[1 2 4] + [2 3 7]= [3 5 11]

Comment: Did you even attempt to solve this on your own? Your code shows no trace of any kind of `for` loop or any other part of your intention

Comment: @ UnholySheep Do you think you can refer me to some online resources for this kind of problem?

Comment: @UnholySheep Any references to how to solve my problem?

Comment: @Shibli -Can you help me? I could really use some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    for (int j=0; j<size; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << "first[" << i << "][" << j << "]" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> first[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shibli- So what you did was you created a for loop to go through all rows and columns of the first matrix and then store each element into the first matrix? Where would the actual values come into play at? I know that each matrix would have 100 elements and then the sum would also have 100 elements too.

Comment: Code asks for a value for each element of matrix and stores whatever you give with `std::cin`. What do you mean with actual values?